# Show items in listview if the chosen dates lays in between a booking

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have two datepickers that shows items in a listview depending on which dates you choose different items show up. I need to show items in listview if the chosen dates lays in between a booking. I've not managed to to this but this is what I've done so far:

These are the two dates from datepickers:

```
public DateTime SDate
    {
        get
        {
            return sDate;
        }

        set
        {
            startDate = value;
        }
    }


    public DateTime EDate
    {
        get
        {
            return eDate;
        }

        set
        {
            eDate = value;
        }
    }
```

This is the method that tells me what date that booking is:

```
public DateTime Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

And here comes the tricky part for me. Cannot figure out how to check the dates and then also add `payment.Date.Value` to it. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
Date = (SDate - EDate) = payment.Date.Value
```

Appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to select items that have a Payment date between the start date and end date, do this

```
if ((payment.Date.Value >= SDate) && (payment.Date.Value <= EDate))
```